# How to set the audio files from my app as a ringtone to my Iphone?

Tags: objective-c

I am struggling with a problem that In my application Im having audio files and I need to set those audio files as Ringtone, Alarm, Email alert or Message tone.As I am new to Sdk I dont know how to do this.

Pleas guys can any one suggest how to get rid of this?

Hope I will get the quick response from your side guys.

Thanks in  advance.
Monish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the users ringtones, and the other tones are fixed. They are actually audio files in the system, but you don't have access ot that from the sdk